# Elasticsearch: Product-variant-price modelling and query problem

Tags: elasticsearch, modeling

I want to use Elasticsearch to improve performance on product search (duh) in an e-commerce solution. We have a data model where a product can have multiple variants and each variant can have one or more prices (sometime quite a substantial number of prices).

The user, query-time, chooses if (s)he wants to return products or variants and only one price should be returned (the lowest valid price, each price have a number of fields like valid from-to and valid customer groups).

My first approach was to denormalize product/variants and have prices as nested fields, but this was quite slow and I had a few problems sorting (I think on price, but the exact details eludes me right now).

Second approach was to totally denormalize so all product/variant/price combination is represented as a document. This approach is much faster (obviously), I can aggregate on `productId` or `variantId` and get the lowest price but the problem is that I cannot sort the aggregates on non-numeric or non-aggregate fields.

Denormalized documents (`productId`, `variantId` are keyword fields, `price` is numeric, `validFrom`/-`To` are date and the rest is text):

```
[
  {
    "productId": "111-222-333",
    "variantId": "aaa-bbb-ccc",
    "product_title": "Mega-product",
    "product_description": "This awesome piece of magic will change your life",
    "variant_title": "Green mega-product",
    "variant_description": "Behold the awesomeness of the green magic mega-product",
    "color": [
      "blue",
      "green"
    ],
    "brand": "DaBrand",
    "validFrom": "2019-06-01T00:00:00Z",
    "validTo": null,
    "price": 399
  },
  {
    "productId": "111-222-333",
    "variantId": "aaa-bbb-ddd",
    "product_title": "Mega-product",
    "product_description": "This awesome piece of magic will change your life",
    "variant_title": "Blue mega-product",
    "variant_description": "Behold the awesomeness of the blue magic mega-product",
    "color": [
      "blue",
      "green"
    ],
    "brand": "DaBrand",
    "validFrom": "2019-06-01T00:00:00Z",
    "validTo": null,
    "price": 499
  },
  {
    "productId": "111-222-333",
    "variantId": "aaa-bbb-ddd",
    "product_title": "Mega-product",
    "product_description": "This awesome piece of magic will change your life",
    "variant_title": "Blue mega-product",
    "variant_description": "Behold the awesomeness of the blue magic mega-product",
    "color": [
      "blue",
      "green"
    ],
    "brand": "DaBrand",
    "validFrom": "2019-06-05T00:00:00Z",
    "validTo": "2019-06-10T00:00:00Z",
    "price": 399
  }
]
```

An example of a working query where I sort on the aggregated price.

```
{
    "size": 1,
    "sort": {
        "product_name_text_en.keyword": "asc"
    },
    "query": {
        // All the query and filtering
    },
    "aggs": {
        "by_product_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "product_id_string",
                "order": {
                    "min_price": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "min_price": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "price_decimal"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, using this approach I cannot find a way to sort on document fields. It is possible (I think) on numeric, boolean and date fields using `bucket_sort`, but I need to be able to sort on, for example, brand or title field (which are text). If it would've been possible to `order` on a top_hits aggregation I would be home free, but that's unfortunately not possible as I understand from the docs (I've also tried it just to make sure).

Can anyone guide me to a better solution? I don't mind if I have to do the query in two steps, but to make that work for sorting I likely need to have a few different "document types", like Product, Variant, ProductPrice and VariantPrice to use depending on the requested sort order. I'm not the far gone so remodelling is definitively on the table, I've considered using join fields, but I'm not sure that would be performant.

Since the number of products and variants (and prices) can be significant - a million products is definitively on the table, I think I will have problems getting Id's from a query (for example filtering on brand and sorting on title) and then sending them into a get-best-price-query.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out by accident when I was reading the docs for another case. It all became very simple when I found out about [Field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-collapse.html). I feel like I should've known about this...

The index have the same model as in my initial question but the query became much simpler:

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    // filter/match stuff, including filtering valid prices.
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "productId",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "least_price",
      "collapse": {
        "field": "price"
      },
      "size": 1,
      "sort": [
        {
          "price": "asc"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "brand.keyword": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

And to return variants instead of products I just collapse on `variantId`

The collapsing is based on `productId` or `variantId` and the `least_price` for the `inner_hits` returns the document with the least price (`asc` sorted by price and picking the first) of the document matching my criterias. Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks ! It's exactly what I'm lookin for. Unfortunately field collapsing is not yet supported in spring-data-elasticsearch.
Did you find another alternative ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I’ve also discovered that it didn’t solve my entire use case, sorting on price descending doesn’t work since sorting takes place before field collapsing. It might be other problems due to this, but they are edge cases which could be handled. For price descending sort I need to do an aggregate first.